# Avoid inserting a particular value into sql table

Tags: sql-server, ssms-2014

I am not sure, if this can be achieved in SQL.

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3) 
VALUES (value1, value2, 999);
```

If the user tries to insert 999 in column3, convert it to null or avoid inserting it.

I am trying to find if I can find any solution from SQL Server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a Check Constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD CHECK (column3<>999);
```

Comment: instead of terminating the statement, can we convert to null- @Mark Kram

Comment: You would have to use instead of triggers to convert 999 to a NULL. You would need both insert and update triggers to accomplish this. I would not recommend this approach though as I strongly dislike the system changing data that is being inserted.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot case the 999 in the insert statement. It really depends on the implementation. Is this strictly in the Database? Is it being called with a java/python/scala library?  In the database, I would recommend the following:

```
set @value1 = val1;
set @value2 = val2;
set @value3 = if(val3=999,NULL,val3);

INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3) 
VALUES (@value1, @value2, @value3);
```

If outside the Database, just use the same logic.